# How two charges of different magnitude can exert equal force

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

Though it seems to be very simple question but I want help where I am lacking.Two charges say one of 10C and other of 1C how can they exert same force.Say a charge of ten coloumb will surely attract or repel the charge of 1C with 10 times.Also keep that mass is same.

Comment: The force is proportional to the product of the charges $\:q_{1}\cdot q_{2}\:$ and inversely proportional to the square of distance $\:r\:$ between them. Mass has nothing to do with this.

Comment: mass was mentioned just to make sure that no oter forces come to play why someone mentions answer as that the heavier or lighter charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with charge **a** with charge $1\, \rm C$ and place it near charge **A** with charge  $1\, \rm C$.
The forces on the two charges **a** and **A** have the same magnitude  $F$ as required by Newton’s third law.

Remove charge **a** and place charge **b** with charge $1\, \rm C$ at exactly the same distant from charge charge **A** as charge **a** was before.
The forces on the two charges **b** and **A** have the same magnitude  $F$.

Add charge **a** to charge **b** at exactly the same distant from charge charge **A** as charge **b** (and **a**) was before.
The forces on the charges **ab** $(=2\, \rm C)$ and charge **A**  $(=1\, \rm C)$ have the same magnitude  $F+F =2F$.

Repeat the process for ten charges **abcdefghij** to find that the force on both charges **abcdefghij**  $(=10\, \rm C)$ and charge **A**  $(=1\, \rm C)$ have the same magnitude $10F$.